# Memory leak -- rasterio.MemoryFile()?

Tags: python-3.x, gdal, rasterio

##### Code:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import psutil
import rasterio

from memory_profiler import profile

@profile
def main():
    
    profile = dict(
    count=1,
    height=30000,
    width=30000,
    nodata=-9999,
    dtype='int16')
    
    print(f"Before array declaration & initialization: {psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2}")
    arr = np.random.randint(0, 20000, size=(30000,30000), dtype='int16')
    print(f"After array declaration & initialization: {psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2}")
    with rasterio.MemoryFile() as memf:
        with memf.open(driver='COG', **profile) as dataset:
            dataset.write(arr, 1)
        print(f"In memfile context: {psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2}")
    print(f"After memfile context: {psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f"Start: {psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2}")
    main()
    print(f"End: {psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2}")
```

##### Output:

```
python -m memory_profiler test_rasterio_memory_file.py 
Start: 71.09765625
Before array declaration & initialization: 71.328125
After array declaration & initialization: 1788.21875
/usr/local/google/home/mahrsee/miniconda3/envs/weather-tools/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasterio/io.py:140: NotGeoreferencedWarning: Dataset has no geotransform, gcps, or rpcs. The identity matrix will be returned.
  return writer(mempath, 'w+', driver=driver, width=width,
ERROR 4: `/vsimem/2ed68c2f-7bed-4d9a-b5e5-3ed6dd7fce17/2ed68c2f-7bed-4d9a-b5e5-3ed6dd7fce17.tif' not recognized as a supported file format.
In memfile context: 5486.76953125
After memfile context: 2433.4921875
Filename: test_rasterio_memory_file.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
     8     71.2 MiB     71.2 MiB           1   @profile
     9                                         def main():
    10                                             
    11     71.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           2       profile = dict(
    12     71.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       count=1,
    13     71.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       height=30000,
    14     71.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       width=30000,
    15     71.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       nodata=-9999,
    16     71.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       dtype='int16')
    17                                             
    18     71.3 MiB      0.2 MiB           1       print(f"Before array declaration & initialization: {psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2}")
    19   1788.2 MiB   1716.9 MiB           1       arr = np.random.randint(0, 20000, size=(30000,30000), dtype='int16')
    20   1788.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       print(f"After array declaration & initialization: {psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2}")
    21   1788.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       with rasterio.MemoryFile() as memf:
    22   1802.7 MiB     14.5 MiB           1           with memf.open(driver='COG', **profile) as dataset:
    23   5486.8 MiB   3684.1 MiB           1               dataset.write(arr, 1)
    24   2433.5 MiB  -3053.3 MiB           1           print(f"In memfile context: {psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2}")
    25   2433.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       print(f"After memfile context: {psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2}")


End: 716.875
```

##### Library/Tool Version:

Python - 3.8.13
rasterio - Version: 1.3.0
GDAL - Version: 3.5.1

Please do observe the increment in memory at Line #23 of 3684.1 MiB and at Line #24  3053.3 MiB is released (when context for `rasterio.MemoryFile()` exit). But why didn't it  release 3684.1 MiB ? Is this a memory leak ?

Also another strange/weird thing to note is that before the start of main() function memory was 71.2 MiB and after its completion it was 716.2 MiB [ 71.2 MiB + (3684.1 MiB - 3053.5 MiB) ] ... isn't it that all the memory should be released on completion of function ?